# Simperium and background NSManagedContext

Tags: core-data, simperium

I'm starting Simperium in the application launch process. All works ok until objects are saved in a context other than the one used to start the simperium instance. Should these "buckets not loaded..." errors be ignored or should I be managing the simperium instance and NSManagedObjectContexts for background threads differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately multiple contexts aren't yet supported. Simperium expects a single context, which clearly isn't ideal. You can track [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/37), or if you're feeling brave take a stab at adding support for it yourself (the library is open source). It'll be a little hairy though.

Comment: Thanks! Just in case it might help someone else, I encountered this using Simperium in a project that also uses MagicalRecord. I found the Simperium errors to be harmless since any operations on background contexts are propagated to the main context. I added a condition in SPManagedObject.configureBucket to check whether the object's context was the main context before logging the error and all seems ok for now.

Comment: Jeffery, when I last looked into this, Simperium syncs weren't correctly triggered when the background context merges with the main context due to the way the notifications work. Though you can no doubt disable any errors as you've done, it's probably a good idea to check that background context changes are indeed being synced successfully.